# OpenType - Two Khmer chars become three before mapping to glyph Ids

Tags: unicode, character-encoding, truetype, opentype

I have an interesting problem with processing Khmer text.

The text "កើ" is a string of length two in Unicode. See snipped below for the char codes.

```js
let textbox = document.getElementById('textbox');
let info = document.getElementById('info');

let text = "កើ"

textbox.setAttribute('value', text);

info.innerHTML = "length: " + text.length + "<br>codes: " + text.split('').map(c => c.charCodeAt(0))
```

```html
<input id="textbox" type="text" style="font-size:80px; width: 2em;"/>
<div id="info"></div>
```

Text renderers seem to compose this text of three glyphs, or replace the three characters with ligatures. So far this is exotic but not unexpected.

Here is the puzzling thing: When I type this text into the Crowbar text shaping debugger at http://www.corvelsoftware.co.uk/crowbar/ using the [Khmer font from Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Khmer), one can see that the two characters are mapped to three glyphs. But the two characters seem to become three characters even before the mapping. Character 6081 appears out of thin air.

[image]

I took a deep dive into the internals of the font file, and there is only one subtable in the `cmap` table, which maps character codes to glpyh ids. This table has format 4, which is pretty standard and only allows one-to-one mappings, so there is no additional glyph inserted during `cmap` processing.

Also, if only the two original char codes are mapped to glyphs, the resulting text will look different, so the third character seems to be necessary.

What step am I missing here that adds the third character before the character to glyph id mapping? There seems to be some preprocessing of the text taking place that I am not aware of.

Comment: This seems to be a science on its own. Here is an article describing in detail how Khmer fonts are created: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/script-development/khmer
THere is actually some preprocessing going on, such as adding a character before vowels.

Comment: I do not know all the details, but stage 1 is to normalize a string. Unicode code point have different normalization. It is very probable that they just do a decomposition, because it is much better to deal diacritics separately (they follow other rules)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Thanks, i will look into this. There is a Javascript normalize() function for strings. But so far I could not make do what I was hoping for.

Comment: You should check shaping engines, e.g. https://harfbuzz.github.io/ (there are few other: one of Microsoft, one of Mac and SIL). These translate strings (and font information) in position and glyphs. It is a complex topic, which I have not yet mastered.

Comment: I'd also recommend asking this over on https://typedrawers.com, instead, since that's where all the font folks hang out.

Comment: You might wrote using wrong vowel:
កើ  and  កេី  these two are different

Answer (score 1):

As @Waruyama suggested, the answer is documented in  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/script-development/khmer.  It is buried in the entry for 'Vowel' in the glossary there, and says

> The shaping engine will take care of pre-pending the syllable, with the glyph piece shaped like U+17C1.

By 'syllable', the specification means the first part of these vowels, which has the same shape as U+17C1 KHMER VOWEL SIGN E.  Therefore HarfBuzz expands the input string from <U+1780, U+17BE> to <U+1780, U+17C1, U+17BE>. At this point, the font has been consulted only to confirm that it has GSUB instructions for the Khmer script.  Next, it applies the cmap table from the font.

Answer (score 0):

You might wrote using wrong vowel:

`កើ (U+1780U+17BE)`  and  `កេី (U+1780U+17C1U+17B8)`  : these two are different.

As if using wrong key of vowel, the glyph still appear as the same but they are constructed from different key.

Try with this https://r12a.github.io/app-conversion/